# How can I get the compensated compound Poisson process in Mathematica

Tags: simulation

Let us consider the following martingale "compensated compound Poisson process"  $M_t=\sum_{k=1}^{N_t} Z_k-\lambda t E(Z)$ where $N_t$ is a Poisson process with intensity $\lambda$, $Z_k$ is iid random variable  and indepent with $N_t$.
If we consider a special case on "Stochastic Calculus for Jump Processes(https://personal.ntu.edu.sg/nprivault/MA5182/stochastic-calculus-jump-processes.pdf)" P703. We have the following figure [image]
The author get it from software R. You can see the original code from the following picture [image]. My problem is that how can I get the similar simulation from Mathematica?

Comment: Please add the Mathematica code you have tried and the problems you have encountered.

Comment: SeedRandom[1];
With[{\[Lambda] = 0.6, \[Mu] = 0.5, x0 = 1}, 
 proc = ItoProcess[m'[t] = y'[t] - \[Lambda] *\[Mu], m[t], {m[0], x0},
    y \[Distributed] CompoundPoissonProcess[
     0.5, ExponentialDistribution[1]]]; 
 rp = RandomFunction[proc, {0., 5., 0.01}]]
ListLinePlot[rp]

Comment: Here is the Mathematica code I have tried. But It doe not work.

Comment: Maybe I should not use the ItoProcess. But  I have no idea to simulate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`TransformedProcess`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TransformedProcess.html) may be helpful.

For example:

```
p = CompoundPoissonProcess[.5, ExponentialDistribution[1]];
tr = TransformedProcess[x[t] - Mean[p[t]], {x \[Distributed] p}, t];
rf = RandomFunction[tr, {0, 100}, 10];
ListPlot[rf, Joined -> True]
```

[image]